# ffmpeg command >> out.log 2>>error.log

Tags: ffmpeg, stdout, stderr

I'm running:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/test -crf 20 -t 00:10:00 ./video/hq/1503411993750.mp4 >> out.log 2>>error.log
```

And expecting `>> out.log 2>>error.log` to result in `stdout` to `out.log` and `stderr` to `error.log`.

When I tail both of these files during the process I get unexpected results. The contents of `error.log` seem to contain `stdout`. I get a constant stream of:

```
frame=191 fps=190 q=26.0 size=229kB time=00:00:04.63 bitrate=404.1
frame=227 fps=149 q=26.0 size=273kB time=00:00:05.83 bitrate=382.8
frame=242 fps=120 q=26.0 size=288kB time=00:00:06.33 bitrate= 372.6
frame=258 fps=101 q=26.0 size=306kB time=00:00:06.86 bitrate= 365.2
frame=273 fps=89 q=26.0 size=324kB time=00:00:07.36 bitrate= 360.1
# ... continued
```

Shouldn't the above be in `out.log`? Is the issue with how I've written the command or something unussual with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all diagnostics messages in `ffmpeg` are sent to `stderr`, so the problem isn't syntax.

> -A normally running ffmpeg task seems to send all it's output (even when there are no errors) to STDERR even with no errors.
>
> This depends on what you mean with "output": ffmpeg sends all
>   diagnostic messages (the "console output") to stderr because its
>   actual output (the media stream) can go to stdout and mixing the
>   diagnostic messages with the media stream would brake the output.

From: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-March/020605.html

---

Another thing I'm unsure of. If the above is true shouldn't `out.log` contain video data, but instead it's always empty.

*(I guess this is because I've specified it to be sent to `./video/hq/1503411993750.mp4` instead)*

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?